# Rails (newbie) - How to store a token variable in a link in db on create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, token

I have a problem with my create action and I don't understand why I am wrong here.

Users can follow a link which contain a token variable. Here is my route.

## routes.rb

```
match "/:token" => "invitations#new", :via => :get
```

On a create action I want the token to be stored in the sender_token instance in my db.

I tried this:

## invitation controller

```
  def new
    @invitation = Invitation.new
  end

  def create
    @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
    if @invitation.save

      # here the pb ???     
      @invitation.sender_token = :token

      session[:invitation] = @invitation
      Mailer.invitation(@invitation).deliver
      redirect_to invite_request_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can't really understand your question or problem. Are the two actions that you've menstioned related? Because the first part your mentioned (in routes.rb) will trigger the **new** method in the controller, while the second might be invoked (if you have the route) when a post is done to the invitation_controller. Also if you get an error, could you add it?

Comment: Hi Augusto I will edit my post to be clearer. I don't have any error but nothing is stored in the db. Thanks!

Comment: Augusto, Are you saying that parameters of the new action (so the token I want to save) are not the same than those on the create action ? and is it for this the token can't be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. 
Please let me know if you think it's the right way to do it!

```
def new
  @invitation = Invitation.new
  session[:token] = params[:token]       # or $test = params[:token] ???
end

def create
  @invitation = Invitation.new(params[:invitation])
  @invitation.sender_token = session[:token]      # or @invitation.sender_id = $test ???
    if @invitation.save
      session[:invitation] = @invitation
      Mailer.invitation(@invitation).deliver
      redirect_to invite_request_path
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be

```
@invitation.sender_token = params[:token]
```